# How to let facebook read a url that is IP restricted

Tags: facebook, ip, restriction

I have a site that has two versions, for one country **A** and for all of the rest, and is restricted by IP,

The thing is that from country A, if they share a URL in facebook (for example); when facebook tries to scan for title, description and image it fails (as actually should),

**Is there a way** to detect that is `facebook/twitter/google` IP and let them read it? (i understand that if the link is clicked outside country A or facebook it will fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some info on the individual websites:

- For Facebook Crawler address info, have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#crawl
- For Twitter, you can have a look here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/troubleshooting#Card_Validator
- For Google, have a look here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en