# Facebook open graph cannot scraped my website meta tag?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook cannot scraped my website data even though I had provided the meta tag, can anyone tell me what wrong in my code?

Here is my meta tag code

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://cyclingevents.my/event/blog/1/3cf2786678c71d93375922900a739d8b"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="I have registered for the Merdeka 12 Hour MTB Endurance 2014. JOIN ME NOW!"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cyclingevents.my/portal/assets/img/Logo-without-wording2.png"/>
<meta name="image" content="https://cyclingevents.my/portal/assets/img/Logo-without-wording2.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="2014-08-30, 7:00 AM, Bukit Merah Laketown Resort, Taiping">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="644400718971332" />
```

Here is my share button code

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-facebook col-lg-offset-3" style="padding-left:80px;padding-right:80px;" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://cyclingevents.my/payment/successful_payment/1200004/1" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Share on Facebook</a>
```

Here is the error from facebook debugger

[image]

here is my website URL

```
https://cyclingevents.my/payment/successful_payment/1200004/1
```

Any idea how to solve my issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you provided is not accessible for non-logged in users, that's why the Facebook Scraper can't access is as well, and therefore not read the OG tags.

If I try to access it, your site redirects me to https://cyclingevents.my/login/sign_in

Comment: thanks tobi, I had remove the checking user login, but now in facebook debugger show me

 "Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable." , but my meta was inside the <head></head>, do you know why?

Comment: Yes, your page renders an error message before the actual HTML page is rendered: `Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/payment.php
Line Number: 555` Therefore, the Scraper sees the result as the result.

Comment: Thanks Tobi again, after I solve the error, its working now, really thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just as a hint, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693156/how-to-let-facebook-read-a-url-that-is-ip-restricted/24693457#24693457 to see how you could restrict the access to your page, and let FB IPs through...

Comment: Thanks you very much for the hint , you are kind and sweet :)